# Set default value for form field when associated query element doesn't return a value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a query that returns the aggregation of the cost of the resources assigned to the company departments every month:

```
TRANSFORM Sum (Resource.Cost) AS ResourceCost
SELECT Department.Name
FROM (Department INNER JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
PIVOT Format([Date],"mmmm");
```

This would return this:

```
DEPARTMENT        January February March April May June July
IT                   200     150    200   100  110 800  920
HumanResources       10      150    200   100  110 500  50
Accounting           150      00    10     20  10  0    330
```

As you can see the values for the next months of this year are empty since those costs aren't returned by the query (they have not been inserted in the data base yet).

Moving on, I have a form that shows this information, including all months of the current year:

```
DEPARTMENT        January February March April May June July August September October November December
IT                   200     150    200   100  110 800  920  #error #error    #error  #error   #error
HumanResources       10      150    200   100  110 500  50   #error #error    #error  #error   #error
Accounting           150      00    10     20  10  0    330  #error #error    #error  #error   #error
```

Unfortunately there is an error for those fields where the query doesn't have any value for the associated cost in that month.

The value is set with something like `=[August]`. Since a valule for August isn't in the result set of the query it shows an error.

I would like to show 0 for all those months without information. I've tried different options such as `=Nz([August];0)` but they didn't work.

Could you tell me how to set a value of 0 for those fields?

Answer (score 2):

Simply specify the field names in `PIVOT...IN ()` clause where non-applicable fields will render as empty columns. You can even use this `IN` clause to re-order the columns:

```
TRANSFORM Sum (Resource.Cost) AS ResourceCost
SELECT Department.Name
FROM (Department INNER JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
PIVOT Format([Date],"mmmm") IN ('January', 'February', 'March', 
                                'April', 'May', 'June', 
                                'July', 'August', 'September', 
                                'October', 'November', 'December')
```

Or reversed order for illustration using `MonthName` + `Month` functions:

```
PIVOT MonthName(Month([Date])) IN ('December', 'November', 'October', 
                                   'September', 'August', 'July', 
                                   'June', 'May', 'April', 
                                   'March', 'February', 'January')
```

Comment: 1+ This is a new one for me - great solution!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `=Nz([August],0)` doesn't work in this scenario is because it's not that the field `[August]` is returning `null` (which would cause `0` to be returned by the `Nz` function), but rather that the field `[August]` **does not exist in the bound query**.

One possible solution is to use conditional aggregation in place of a cross-tab query, e.g.:

```
select
    department.name,
    sum(iif(month([date])=1,resource.cost,0)) as January,
    sum(iif(month([date])=2,resource.cost,0)) as February,
    ...
from
    department inner join ...
group by 
    department.name
```

By checking only the `month` of your `[date]` field, I am assuming that you are only working with a single year's worth of data.

Comment: Hi Lee Mac, thanks for answering. Tomorrow I'll give a try to the query you suggest. However I'd rather not modify the query, it's actually more complex than it seems, I simplified it for this question. I wonder if there is some kind of function that would allow me to check the existence of the data at the form, something like, making it up: `=ifExists([august];0)`.